# Send urlencoded POST request with wget

Tags: bash, curl, post, wget

The following `curl` will send a `POST` request with the `url` parameter automatically urlencoded:

```
u="url=http://somewhere.net?param1=val1&param2=val2"
curl -XPOST --data-urlencode "$u" http://example.com
```

However, I need to issue this request from a system that does not have
`curl` installed.

Is there a way to achieve the same with `wget`? Can `$u` be urlencoded automatically by `wget` or another program that *might* be on a minimal linux installation?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/cdown/1163649

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as suggested in the comments by @Roadowl, bash itself can urlencode data, the wget invocation could look like

```
wget --post-data=$(printf "url="; urlencode $u) http://example.com
```

using urlencode implementation from https://gist.github.com/cdown/1163649 ,

```
urlencode() {
    # urlencode <string>
    old_lc_collate=$LC_COLLATE
    LC_COLLATE=C

    local length="${#1}"
    for (( i = 0; i < length; i++ )); do
        local c="${1:i:1}"
        case $c in
            [a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]) printf "$c" ;;
            *) printf '%%%02X' "'$c" ;;
        esac
    done

    LC_COLLATE=$old_lc_collate
}
```

.. probably won't work will null bytes though, given that bash doesn't like null bytes and probably won't allow them in variables